# Is there a way to conditionally select different initializer lists for a c++ ranged-for loop?

Tags: c++

I would like to rearrange this code:

```
if (x_can_be_true) {
  for (x : {false, true}) {
    do_work(x);
  }
} else {
  do_work(false);
}
```

so `do_work` is called only once.

Conceptually, I would like to do this:

```
for (x : (x_can_be_true ? {false, true} : {false})) {
  do_work(x);
}
```

Any suggestions how to make that code actually compile?

EDITs:
`do_work` is a simplified placeholder for the real-world problem.
it's many lines of code that depend on many parameters from prior lines.
the objective of the question is to find a pattern that avoids repeating those many lines. cause that's not-good coding practice. ;->

i could make it a function with many parameters. or use a parameter block. but... ick. ;->

Comment: For simplicity: `do_work(false); if (x_can_be_true) { do_work(true); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
std::set<bool> vals = {false};
vals.emplace(x_can_be_true);

for (auto x : vals)
   do_work(x);
```

Answer (score 8):

What about

```
do_work(false);
if (x_can_be_true)
    do_work(true);
```

This is equivalent to your simple example, but may not be a solution to what you're *really* trying to do.